# Jquery Animate() not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

There is an animating effect in the " Featured Projects " part of this site [here](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_41832/index.html#/) .

I'm trying to make that for my site and I actually did that at first about a month ago. But now surprisingly it is not working at all and just kind of ambiguous for me to figure that out what the issue could be.

Am I choosing the wrong library, is there a problem in my scripts, or is it a bug?

HTML.

```
      <a class="MainMiddleTwoEach MMTE1"  href="#" title="This is the title 1">
           <label class="MainMiddleTwoLabel1"></label>
           <span class="MainMiddleTwoLabel2"></span>    
      </a>
```

JS.

```
      $('.MainMiddleTwoEach').mouseenter(function (e) {
            pageId = $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).children('label').animate({ top: '150px' }, 300);
            $(this).children('label').animate({ top: '-100px' }, 300);
            $(this).children('span').animate({ top: '20px' }, 300);
            $(this).children('span').animate({ top: '230px' }, 300);
        }).mouseleave(function (e) {
            $(this).children('label').animate({ top: '130px' }, 300);
            $(this).children('label').animate({ top: '80px' }, 300);
            $(this).children('span').animate({ top: '-10px' }, 300);
            $(this).children('span').animate({ top: '55px' }, 300);
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K4Ak2/3

Answer (score 8):

You need to set the element's position to `relative` or `absolute` in order to use the `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` properties.

Check out my edit here: http://jsfiddle.net/K4Ak2/4/

I've added one line in the CSS

```
label, span { position: relative; }
```

It should work as expected.

Comment: Tim, believe me that in my real codes they are set position:absolute. But I'm still getting no result in my project and I think there is something wrong in there rather than in scripts or css. but Thank you anyway.

Comment: The "Featured Projects" page doesn't contain any Javascript that is supposed to animate anything. Instead of supplying a JSFiddle that doesn't represent the issue correctly, can you tell us what's wrong on the demo page you shared? Give us some actual intel man.

Comment: There is something wrong in my codes and I'm trying to solve it by myself. Thank you for giving it time Tim.

Answer (score 3):

From the jQuery api for Animate: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> Directional properties (top, right, bottom, left) have no discernible
>   effect on elements if their position style property is static, which
>   it is by default.

You may try setting the position to 'relative'

Comment: They are actually set position:absolute and yes here it is working now but not there in my project. But hey thx for this piece of info.